# How to resubmit an android app on play store after rejection

Tags: android, console, google-play

Well i uploaded an android app and uploaded it.Today in morning i got an email from google your app rejected now i corrected all the problems stated.I want to resubmit the app again.How to resubmit android app as resubmit button is not highlighted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)